# Could not load Microsoft.Build.dll in Windows Phone 8 SDK and VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have installed the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and Visual Studio 2012 Premium with Update 1. When I create now a new phone project I get three errors:

> Error 1   The "CompileXaml" task could not be instantiated from
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.
>
> Error 2   The "CompileXaml" task has been declared or used incorrectly,
>   or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and
>   the assembly name.
>
> Error 3   The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:PhoneApp24".   C:\PhoneDevelopment\PhoneApp24\PhoneApp24\App.xaml

While googling I found some guys out there who have similar errors while using Windows 8 in a virtual machine. But in my case I have installed everything on my laptop. I have also already uninstalled VS2012 and the SDK. But after the reinstallation I still get the same exceptions.

Can someone please give me some hints?

Comment: Can you confirm if this is Windows 8 RTM, and not Consumer Preview?

Comment: Hi Paul, yes I can confirm that I have a normal Windows 8 pro, 64bit english from my academic alliance msdn account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours trying to get the sdk working I finally did a window recovery. Since windows 8 this is now a very quick process. Just insert the windows cd and run the setup again. If you choose the right option you can reinstall windows 8 without loosing your data. After 10 minutes your system reboots and you have to fill in again some data.

After that I installed the SDK. No error poped out and everything went very smoothly. Then I started VS express, created a project and built it successfully!

After the SDK installation I found two additional tiles on my desktop: "Hyper-V Manager" and "Hyper-V Virtual Machine...". I am pretty sure that those two tiles were not when I installed the SDK before. So I guess that I have had some problems with my virtual machine and that this was probably the source of the building exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well after trying to create a project using a VMWare shared folder for the file. Try creating the project in a local directory if you are using a VM then the project will build fine. Apparently the assembly files are either not downloaded properly or do not have permission to be read. More than likely it's the namespace itself causing the issue.

Error   1   Could not load the assembly file://\vmware-host\shared folders\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NewApp.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information.

Comment: Hi MarkM, thank you for your response. My Project resides in the usual Documents/VS2012/Projects folder. I have also tried to create a project directly on c:/myProject. I have now checked the block-state of the Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.dll - but it is not blocked at all.

Comment: Are you able to build any examples?

Comment: No unfortunately not. All installed templates give me the two CompileXaml exceptions. Exception three (LocalizedStrings) appears only from time to time. I have also loaded some example projects from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ without any luck. Therefore there has to be any missconfiguration in my system.

Comment: I have to ask even if it seems obvious but have you tried uninstalling completely and only loading the SDK with VS Express? Also, run the installer as Administrator.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions but unfortunately without any luck. After uninstalling and reinstalling the sdk a lot of the configurations are still there (registration, last edited projects and so on). Therefore I guess that the underlying problem was also not uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Try running VS2012 as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trying to run one of the [Office 365 API samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Windows) and it turned out to be a missing file in the solution. Specifically, the solution was expecting a temp PFX certificate at the root of the project. I removed that and the build errors stopped.